# WP7 PivotItem doesn't accept foreground if Pivot has set foreground

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

Having the xaml as below:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="TEST" Foreground="#FF0000FF">
        <controls:PivotItem Foreground="#FF00FF00">
```

the second foreground color is not used for title (only for content)... The goal is to have Pivot.Title with different color than the PivotItem.Title... this works for Panorama and PanoroamaItem - is this a bug in wp7 control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way in which the styles and templates are defined for the `Pivot` does not allow you to specify the foreground color for the `PivotItem` in this way, however you can apply a different `HeaderTemplate` as follows:

```
     <controls:Pivot Title="TEST" Foreground="#FF0000FF">
            <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FF00FF00" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
```

Comment: WORKS! Thanks! Two questions though: 1. Can I make this a default for every pivot that I use across my app? 2. How did you know that? How can I check that kind of stuff in the future?

Comment: 1. You can create a Style without a key, which would then be applied to all instances, and specify this value for the HeaderTemplate property. You don't need to modify any other properties, just this one. 2. Years of practice and experience working with the Microsoft technology stack and specifically XAML-related technologies, e.g. WPF, Silverlight, and WP7 :)